# Is $S$ is subring of $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider  $S = \Bbb C[x^5]$, as  a subset of $T =\Bbb C[x]$, the ring  of all complex polynomials.
Now my question is that

Is  $S$ is  subring  of $T$ ?

My attempts  :  I thinks  Yes  because  $S$ is a subset of $T$

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Check also $S$ is closed under subtraction, closed under multiplication, and it contains the multiplicative identity $1$.

Comment: Its a subset but as said, you need to check that it is closed under addition, contains the additive inverse of each element, it is closed under multiplication and contains the unit element 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1\in\Bbb C[x^5]$ since it is just the zero power of $x^5$.

Now, given $p,q\in\Bbb C[x^5]$ we have that $p(x)=a_nx^{5n}+a_{n-1}x^{5(n-1)}+\ldots+a_1x^5+a_0$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ with $a_i\in\Bbb C$, and $q(x)=b_mx^{5m}+b_{m-1}x^{5(m-1)}+\ldots+b_1x^5+b_0$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$ with $b_i\in\Bbb C$. Therefore, if $n\ge m$, $p(x)-q(x)=a_nx^{5n}+\ldots+(a_m-b_m)x^{5m}+\ldots+(a_0-b_0)\in\Bbb C[x^5]$; and if $m\ge n$, $p(x)-q(x)=-b_mx^{5m}-b_{m-1}x^{5(m-1)}+\ldots+(a_n-b_n)x^{5n}+\ldots+(a_0-b_0)\in\Bbb C[x^5]$.

For the product take the usual expression of $p$ and $q$ as elements of $\Bbb C[x]$ with their coefficients being $a_i$ and $b_j$ respectively. Then $p(x)q(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{m+n}d_lx^l$, with $d_l=\sum_{i+j=l}a_ib_j$. Since $i\mid5$ and $j\mid5$ always, then $l=i+j\mid5$ always, so $p(x)q(x)\in\Bbb C[x^5]$.

Therefore $\Bbb C[x^5]$ is a subring.