# $\mathbb{Z_9}$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ because Choose the correct option

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb{Z_9}$  is not a  subring of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$  because

Choose the correct option

$a)$ $\mathbb{Z_9}$  is not a  subset  of $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$

$b)$GCD$(9,12) = 3\neq 1$

$c)$ $9$ doesnot divide  $12$

I thinks  option $c)$  will be correct by Lagrange Theorem

Comment: Can you explain why you think that?

Comment: @fleablood  lagrange theorem

Comment: So Legrange Theorem says the order of every subgroup of a finite group divides the order of a group. And as rings are groups (under their primary operation (in this case addition)) that would apply to rings as well.  And the order of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is $12$ and the order of $\mathbb Z_9$ is $9$ and $9\not \mid 12$.  Yep.... seems like you've figured it out.

Comment: thanks u @fleablood

Comment: .... and a) is obviously false as $Z_9 \subset Z_{12}$ and b) is not a requirement of subrings.  In fact by legrange the gcd of (non trivial) subrings must *never* be $1$.

Comment: @fleablood  can u  give me any hints     
 ...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005613/is-s-is-subring-of-t

Comment: I don't really have any more to add to i707107's hint.  Need to show it is closed undo addition and multiplication, and that the identitys of C[x] are in C[x^5] and that every element has an additive inverse.

Comment: @fleablood (a) isn't obviously false as you have suggested. It depends on what definition of $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_{9}$ is one using. If you consider $\Bbb{Z}_{9}=\{[0]_9, [1]_9, \ldots, [8]_9\}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_{12}=\{[0]_{12}, [1]_{12}, \ldots, [11]_{12}\}$ as quotients of $\Bbb{Z}$ by the relevant congruence relation, then $\Bbb{Z}_{9}$ isn't a subset of $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$.

Comment: @Anurag good point.  But Z_9 need not not be a subset....  It only is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice and justification are fine.  In particular: in order for $\Bbb Z_9$ to be a subring of $\Bbb Z_{12}$, the group $(\Bbb Z_9,+)$ would have to be a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z_{12},+)$.  However, Lagrange's theorem says that since $9$ does not divide $12$, this cannot be the case.

Comment: Why, the option **(a)** is not correct! Notice, $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{9Z}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{12Z}$

Comment: @A Apparently there are multiple correct options then